# Combine JS with HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a link that opens a popup video when clicked. I was able to get it to work so far. However, I was wondering if there is a way for me to combine the HTML and JS code into 1. That way, I will not have to call the JS.

**HTML**

```
<style>
.mfp-title {
position:absolute;
color: #FFF;
background: maroon;
}
</style>

<a class="video" title="Living the Mission, A Perspective from Residential Life Staff at Boston College" href="http://www.bc.edu/content/dam/files/offices/reslife/mov/Living%20the%20Mission%20%20A%20Perspective%20from%20Residential%20Life%20Staff%20at%20Boston%20College.mp4">Open video</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.video').magnificPopup({
type: 'iframe',


iframe: {
 markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
            '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>'+
          '</div>'
},
callbacks: {
markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
 values.title = item.el.attr('title');
}
}


});
```

If that's not possible, how can I go about calling the JS file. If I do something like this

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

The video opens in full screen and user is taken to a different page. I don't want to have the user go to another page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you used the `<script>` tag, did you place it in the `<head>` or at the end just inside the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: Either way, it should work as long as you wrap your script in a call to `$(document).ready`.

Comment: I tried both, placing it at the top before the <style> and at the bottom after the video link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEaPbE

Comment: Just for fun, see if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/rr4ufu0j/) does what you want, and if so, check out how JSFiddle manages the separate JS and HTML inputs. Basically, they set the `window.onload` handler to execute your script.

Comment: And also try [this updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yywBgR). I also noticed you left out the JQuery script tag in the Codepen.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEaPbE I am just wondering if there is a way for me to have the JS code in HTML. Instead of having 2 different files

Comment: Well, yes, that's what the `<script>` tag is for. If you don't specify a `src` attribute, all the code inside the tag will be run.

Comment: It's weird on Codepen because they automatically put your code in the "JS" frame into a script tag _after_ inserting script tags for your declared dependencies. When you place the script inline in the HTML frame, your code ends up _before_ jQuery and magnific are loaded, so it throws an error (`$ is not defined`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just wondering if there is a way for me to have the JS code in
>   HTML. Instead of having 2 different files

Yes, just wrap it inside a `<script>` tag check this [Javascript Where To](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
 <body>
  <a class="video" title="Living the Mission, A Perspective from Residential Life Staff at Boston College" href="http://www.bc.edu/content/dam/files/offices/reslife/mov/Living%20the%20Mission%20%20A%20Perspective%20from%20Residential%20Life%20Staff%20at%20Boston%20College.mp4">Open video</a>
  <script>
$('.video').magnificPopup({
type: 'iframe',
iframe: {
 markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>'+
            '<div class="mfp-title">Some caption</div>'+
          '</div>'
  },
     callbacks: {
      markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
      values.title = item.el.attr('title');
     }
   }
  });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Second Option (good practice)**

You can do the follow put the css into  `styles.css`  and put the Js code into the file name `myScript.js`.

Now i create this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (hope this is what you want.), since Jsfiddle wrap for you the onDomReady Option, this is how the html document should look.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
 <body>
  <a class="video" title="Living the Mission, A Perspective from Residential Life Staff at Boston College" href="http://www.bc.edu/content/dam/files/offices/reslife/mov/Living%20the%20Mission%20%20A%20Perspective%20from%20Residential%20Life%20Staff%20at%20Boston%20College.mp4">Open video</a>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

With this the html will load first the `<a>` tag, and later will load the `.js` Script

You can also use `$(document).ready`([jQuery](https://jquery.com)) as @Austin Mullins suggest, but for this example this is ok.

Hope you get it

Comment: I think the confusion was caused by the way Codepen constructs the iframe HTML. Be sure to include the dependencies before the user code.

Comment: @AustinMullins It's a little odd that in CodePen video opens in the same page but in JSFiddle the video opens in a new page. Any thooughts?

Comment: In which JSFiddle? In the one I linked? It opened in the same page for me in Chrome.

Comment: Basically, if the Javascript fails for some reason, your link will work as a regular link, changing the browser's location to the video (a new page).

Comment: Seems like the video opens as a regular link in the browser. So I think my JavaScript is failing for some reason.

Comment: @Agent_Sully it will be nice if you create a new SO about the JS code since this issue was about ` I was wondering if there is a way for me to combine the HTML and JS code into 1` and that was solved on the given soultion